# Запуск процесса в памяти в бесконечном цикле

Tags: c++, linux, c

Написать программу, которая бы запускала в памяти еще один процесс и оставляла бы его работать в бесконечном цикле. При повторном запуске программа должна убирать запущенный ранее процесс из памяти (можно использовать kill).

Обязательно использование такой функции как Fork().

Нашел подобный вариант, вопрос, как заставить созданный процесс работать в бесконечном цикле, а при повторном запуске программы удалить его:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <spawn.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void test_fork_exec(void);

int main(void) {
  test_fork_exec();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void test_fork_exec(void) {
  pid_t pid;
  int status;
  puts("Testing fork/exec");
  fflush(NULL);
  pid = fork();
  switch (pid) {
  case -1:
    perror("fork");
    break;
  case 0:
    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", (char *) 0);
    perror("exec");
    break;
  default:
    printf("Child id: %i\n", pid);
    fflush(NULL);
    if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != -1) {
      printf("Child exited with status %i\n", status);
    } else {
      perror("waitpid");
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Также, интересует одна вещь, что делает эта строка.

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", (char *) 0);
```

Comment: >>Также, интересует одна вещь, что делает эта строка.,<< Создаёт дочерний процесс и передаёт ему управление. В вашем случае, это происходит внутри Fork-а, значит, передаётся управление только от дочернего потока Fork-а.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, >>waitpid(pid, &status, 0)<< не заморозит программу, и не будет ждать завершения, а вернёт статус сразу, хотя, не знаю что скрывается за флагом "0", возможно, он делает ожидание синхронным, и я не прав.

Comment: >>как заставить созданный процесс работать в бесконечном цикле<< Замените запуск дочернего процесса на бесконечный цикл. Используя общую память определяйте, запущен ли процесс, или ещё нет, если процесс висит в памяти, кидайте семафор в общую память, и завершайте все процессы.

Comment: В общем, за вашим вопросом стоит куча теории. Без неё ответы которые вам дадут будут не понятны.

Comment: >>(char *) 0<< Вот это вот извращение, рекомендую заменить хотя бы на NULL...

Answer (score 0):

> как заставить созданный процесс работать в бесконечном цикле

Для этого надо сделать две вещи:

1) Заменить строку

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", (char *) 0);
```

На бесконечный цикл. Ну, что-то вроде:

while(1) sleep(10);

2) Убрать ожидание завершения дочернего процесса в главном:

```
waitpid(pid, &status, 0)
```

Иначе никогда не завершится и основная программа.

> при повторном запуске программы удалить его

Для этого Вместо строки

```
printf("Child id: %i\n", pid);
```

выполните запись значения pid в некий текстовый файл. А Ваша главная программа, в начале своей работы, должна проверять наличие этого файла (смотрите про pid-файл) и, если он существует, должна прочитать значение pid, послать сигнал убиваемому процессу:

```
kill(pid, SIGTERM);
```

и удалить pid-файл.

> Также, интересует одна вещь, что делает эта строка.
>
> `execl("/bin/ls", "ls", (char *) 0);`

Этот вызов ни в коем случае НЕ создаёт новый процесс. Он, внутри существующего адресного простанства, заменяет текущий процесс другим. Вот как об этом написано в man:

> The  exec()  family  of  functions  replaces  the current process
>   image with a new process image.

Т.е. для того, что бы запустить из процесса А процесс программы В, необходимо сначала создать КОПИЮ процесса А (с помощью fork), а затем заменить в копии процесс А на процесс В с помощью одной из функций из семейства exec.

Т.е. данная строка, в адресном пространстве копии Вашего основного процесса запускает программу *ls*. Параметр *(char *) 0* сообщает функции *execl* о том, что программа *ls* запускается БЕЗ параметров командной строки.

Функции этого семейства делают одно и тоже, но различаются способом передачи в новый процесс переменных командной строки и ENV-переменных.